# using Supervisord with Zend App, redirects seem to be killing it

Tags: php, zend-framework, supervisord

I have a Zend Application that is running fine.

I have created a Zend Queue script in my library to run some emailing process to members of the site.

The application has many Models that are working well, but when I try and initiate the application in my queue script, it doesn't run.

The only reason I can see for this is a custom helper that extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector. This redirector checks if https is required.

Without initiating the application the run around I have to do to get my queue is nigh impossible.

In my script I am calling from Supervisrd, I am setting up my environment and $application->bootstrap()->run();

I then call the scripts class, but it does not venture past the ->run().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirector helper calls exit(), which is why it's not working. I'd rewrite the endpoint to remove the call to redirect, or write a different endpoint for consumption by the CLI job handled by supervisord.